# Windows- wget use of --background and -O

Tags: batch-file, output, wget

I have a problem with my batch command line, which is :

```
for /l %%X in (1, 1, 100) do wget      --background -q --no-check-certificate -O ->>donnees_wget "https://aaaa/%%X"
```

the "->>" allows to append to one file all the downloads.

I can not use background(--background) and saving in output(-O) file together and I don't understand that.
My error message is "the processus can not access to the file because it's used by another processus"

Has anyone an idea about the problem?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>>` is not handled by wget, but cmd. Each time you start a wget process, you are asking cmd to sent the output of this command to the file, but you can not have two processes redirecting its output to the same file at the same time (not it batch scripts)

So, the only way to do what you are indicating is start only one instance of wget, that will go to background to do its work, adding all the output to the same file.

To get this, you will need to generate a temporary file where to store the urls to be processed by wget.

```
@echo off

    set "tempFile=%temp%\wgetTest"
    (for /l %%X in (1 1 5) do (
        echo(https://aaaa/%%X
    ))>"%tempFile%"

    wget -i "%tempFile%" --background --no-check-certificate -o wget.log -O donnees_wget
```

If --background is not used (which detaches the wget process from the console), instead of generating a temporary file, the generated list can be piped into wget, using `-` (stdin) as the file from where the urls are to be retrieved

```
@echo off

    set "tempFile=%temp%\wgetTest"
    (for /l %%X in (1 1 5) do (
        echo(https://aaaa/%%X
    )) | wget -i - --no-check-certificate -o wget.log -O donnees_wget
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
I though background would allow me to make multiple simultaneous request, if it's not possible in batch file, what is background use for ?
I'm trying to show to a friend that windows can be as fast as Mac,
would you have any idea to improve the speed of my download?
I though about Curl fonction, which seems to be faster.

Comment: @user3137701, you can use `--background` in a batch file. What you can not do is to have multiple instances of wget writing its output to the same file at the same time, neither in windows or mac. wget and curl are tools designed to solve different problems. If what you need is speed and the functions in wget, then, probably, what you need is HTTTrack (both GUI and CLI).